# How to display the list of data in loop using react js

Tags: reactjs

iam trying to display the list in table using react.Api response in array format. This is my code

```
class BuyerList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const merchantId = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userData'));
    this.state = {
      buyerDetails: [],
      merchantId: merchantId
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    PostData("buyers_list", { merchantId: this.state.merchantId }).then(
      result => {
        this.setState({
          buyerDetails: result
        });
      }
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <tbody>
        {buyerDetails.map(buyers_list => (
          <tr key={buyers_list.mbId}>
            <td class="text-center">
              <input type="checkbox" class="i-checks" name="input[]" />
            </td>
            <td> {buyers_list.mbId}</td> <td>Rohit</td>
            <td>+432 955 908</td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs btn-block">
                Add Order
              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        ))}
    </tbody>
    );
  }
}
export default BuyerList;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add **this.state**

```js
render() {
    const { buyerDetails } = this.state;
    return (
      <tbody>
        {buyerDetails && buyerDetails.map(buyers_list => (   // <-- here
```

And fix setState

```js
 componentDidMount() {
    PostData("buyers_list", { merchantId: this.state.merchantId }).then(
      result => {
        this.setState({
          buyerDetails: result && result.buyers_list  // <-- this line updated
        });
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: Iam getting error  "TypeError: this.state.buyerDetails.map is not a function"

Comment: lil bit updated my response @xyz but I think problem is that your response is not array, try to console.log your result in componentDidMount and transform data to be sure that buyerDetails will be array

Comment: My api  response{
    "message": "Success",
    "buyers_list": [
        {
            "bId": "1",
            "Buyername": "Ramesh",
            
        },
        {
            "bId": "2",
            "Buyername": "Rakesh",
           
        }
    ]
}